# Is there a way to add a link to the Home Screen without creating a Web App?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple web page that I would like to give users the option of adding to their homescreen by pressing a button. The desired behavior is that it adds a link to the web page just like it would if you did `⋮` > `Add to Home Screen`.

But all the resources I can find are about adding "web apps" to the home screen. I can setup a manifest, create icons, write various JavaScripts that will inevitably break

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria
[image]

but ideally there would be a way to just create a link to my web page that uses the favicon as the Home Screen icon and not have to write any brittle JavaScript or create a manifest file. Something like `button.OnClick += function() { document.addToHomeScreen(); }` that would prompt the user to add the link to their Home Screen.

Comment: No, the user has to manually set a bookmark

Comment: `brittle JavaScript`  What's that, is it the new name for ES2019?.